# Откуда такое название?

Tags: этимология

Почему блатная речь называется "феня"? Откуда возникло такое название?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как всегда в подобных случаях достоверной этимологии нет.
Я не исключаю происхождение от "Офеня", но надо иметь в виду, что само это слово возможно происходит от еврейского (идиш, но туда попало из иврита) слова "офен" - способ (в нескольких значениях). Но в русский "феня" могло попасть и минуя офеней: "Битуй беофен" — способ выражаться. Отсюда и "ботать по фене".

Есть ещё версии, но ещё менее состоятельные.

Answer (score 1):

Я слышала, что это связано с деятельностью **офеней** - коммивояжеров, странствующих торговцев. Работа у них была опасная, поэтому они выработали тайный "офенский" язык. Это и называлось "ботать по фене".
Видимо, потом этот термин перешел на другой жаргон - блатной.